# I deleted my outlook account from folder directly and i want to add new account in outlook

Tags: outlook

I deleted my outlook account from the folder directly and I want to add a new account in outlook.
[This image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozzye.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to clean the registry.
For Outlook 2013 delete all under 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles